# Trying to Install Snowflake ODBC Drivers in a Docker Image in a Windows Container

Tags: c#, .net, windows, docker, containers

I am new to docker, containers, etc., so trying to figure this out.

An error occurs when I try to run the powershell code to install the ODBC driver.  I tried to utilize chocolatey, but it also throws an error for me.

```
 => ERROR [3/6] RUN Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i', 'C:\\snowflake_odbc.msi', '/quiet', '/norestart
0.701 runc run failed: unable to start container process: exec: "powershell": executable file not found in $PATH
```

The executable is in the path listed, so uncertain why it still says it can't find it.

Code Below

```
# Use a base image with .NET Framework runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /App

# Set the shell to PowerShell for easier script processing
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Copy the Snowflake ODBC installer from the host to the container
COPY ./scripts/snowflake_odbc.msi C://

# Install the Snowflake ODBC driver
RUN Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i', 'C:\\snowflake_odbc.msi', '/quiet', '/norestart' -NoNewWindow -Wait; \
    Remove-Item -Force C:\\snowflake_odbc.msi

# Set up your DSN for Snowflake (optional, depending on your application's connection method)
RUN powershell Add-OdbcDsn -Name "Database Name" -DriverName "Snowflake" -Platform "64-bit" -DsnType "System" -SetPropertyValue @("Server=www.servername.com", "Database=db_name", "Warehouse=warehouse_name1", "Schema=schema1", "Role=role1", "Tracing(0-6)=4", "Proxy=proxy.hostname.com:80", "Trusted_Connection=Yes")

# Copy your built .NET application into the container
COPY . ./

# Open proxy port 80 for the Snowflake DSN
EXPOSE 80

# Command to run your application
ENTRYPOINT ["Report.exe"]

# Input to the executable
CMD ["Auto-Run"]
```

I want to:

- Install a snowflake ODBC driver so my application using a local file
- Run a .exe that was created with .NET #C.  The application is already compiled and created.  The application makes changes to some snowflake tables, then queries the data and then sends out an e-mail.

Actually preparing the container for ECS with fargate, so that is a whole other thing I am learning.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Are you sure your base image is windows based?

Comment: The image should be windows based.  I changed the image so it has powershell installed but then I need to add in .NET Core I believe.

This is the base image I am using now:
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019